# download previous iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, version

Hi does anyone know where I can download iPhone sdk 2.0 and 2.2.1 . I upgraded to the latest version of the sdk (3.1.2) and it broke my application.

In the 3.1.2 installer it gave option to install the 2.2 sdk but it doesn't show up as an option in xcode when I try to execute my app.  The earliest version it will show me is 2.2.1

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Officially" you're not able to downgrade your iPhone once upgraded and archiving copies is possibly copyright infringement but [there are sites](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) out there that host copies if you want to try anyway.

Comment: Thanks Stephen but what about for the actual sdk running on your machine?